# Error in implementation of Double Linked List

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, doubly-linked-list

I wrote a program for double linked list in Python after understanding the algorithm.However only certain sections of the functionalities are working.This is my code below

```
class Node(object):

    def __init__(self,d):
        self.next_node = None
        self.prev_node = None
        self.data = d

class DoublyLinkedList(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None
        self.size = 0

    def add(self,d):
        new_node = Node(d)
        if self.tail:
            self.tail.next_node = new_node
            new_node.next_node = None
            new_node.prev_node = self.tail
        else:
            self.head = new_node
            self.tail = new_node
            new_node.prev_node = None
        self.size+=1

    def addBeg(self,d):
        new_node = Node(d)
        current_node = self.head
        current_node.prev_node = new_node
        new_node.prev_node = None
        new_node.next_node = current_node
        self.head = new_node
        self.size+=1

    def add_at(self,d,index):
        new_node = Node(d)
        previous_node = None
        current_node = self.head
        i = 0
        while i<index and current_node:
            previous_node = current_node
            current_node = current_node.next_node
            i+=1
        #once it reaches the desired index
        if i==index:
            previous_node.next_node = new_node
            new_node.prev_node = previous_node
            new_node.next_node = current_node
            current_node.prev_node = new_node
            self.size+=1
            return True
        else:
            return False                #list ain't too long


    def remove(self,d):
        previous_node = None
        current_node = self.head
        while current_node:
            if current_node.data == d:
                if previous_node:  #the node is somewhere in between
                    previous_node.next_node = current_node.next_node
                    current_node.next_node.prev_node = previous_node
                else:
                    #it is the first node
                    self.head = current_node.next_node
                    current_node.next_node.prev_node = None
                self.size -= 1
                return True

            previous_node = current_node
            current_node = current_node.next_node
        return False

    def search(self,d):
        current_node = self.head
        while current_node:
            if current_node.data == d:
                return True
            current_node = current_node.next_node
        return False

    #traverse through the linked list and store the elements in a list
    def to_list(self):
        lis = []
        current_node = self.head
        while current_node:
            lis.append(current_node.data)
            current_node = current_node.next_node
        return lis

dll = DoublyLinkedList()
```

When I try to insert multiple elements using the add function,it behaves strange.For eg if I try to add three elements,it shows only the first and last

```
ll.add(40)
ll.add(50)
ll.add(60)
print(ll.to_list())
```

I get the output as [40,60]

The second problem is if I remove everthing else and keep just one element

```
#removed all other elements
ll.add(70)
```

I get 'no attribute' error.What's going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in add function,Forgot to update the **self.tail**.

```
def add(self,d):
    new_node = Node(d)
    if self.tail:
        self.tail.next_node = new_node
        new_node.next_node = None
        new_node.prev_node = self.tail
        self.tail=new_node #change is here
    else:
        self.head = new_node
        self.tail = new_node
        new_node.prev_node = None
    self.size+=1
```

Another problem in removing last node.

```
def remove(self,d):
    previous_node = None
    current_node = self.head
    while current_node:
        if current_node.data == d:
            if previous_node:  #the node is somewhere in between
                #print(d)
                previous_node.next_node = current_node.next_node
                if current_node.next_node is None: #deleting last node
                    current_node.prev_node=None
                else:
                    current_node.next_node.prev_node = previous_node
            else:
                #it is the first node
                self.head = current_node.next_node
                current_node.next_node.prev_node = None
            self.size -= 1
            return True

        previous_node = current_node
        current_node = current_node.next_node
    return False
```

[Working Code.](https://ideone.com/gqFy0E) Hope this will help.